# Jquery replaceWith not working on multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I created this script which works nice:

```js
  $(function() {
      $(".decorrer").click(function(e) {
        x = jQuery('#1').clone().attr("id", "dinamics");
        jQuery('#dinamics').replaceWith(jQuery(x));
      });
      $(".Futuras").click(function(e) {
        x = jQuery('#2').clone().attr("id", "dinamics");
        jQuery('#dinamics').replaceWith(jQuery(x));
      });
      $(".Passadas").click(function(e) {
        x = jQuery('#3').clone().attr("id", "dinamics");
        jQuery('#dinamics').replaceWith(jQuery(x));
      });
      $(".2017").click(function(e) {
        x = jQuery('#sete').clone().attr("id","something");
        jQuery('#something').replaceWith(jQuery(x));
        });
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3" id="status">
  <ul>
    <li class="decorrer"><a href="#">A decorrer</a></li>
    <li class="Futuras"><a href="#">Futuras</a></li>
    <li class="Passadas"><a href="#">Passadas</a></li>
    <li class="2017"><a href="#">Passadas</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-7" id="dinamics">
 </div>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="1">
     <p>content1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
     <p>content2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
        <div class="col-md-1" id="years">
            <ul>
                <li class="2016"><a href="#">2017</a></li>
                <li class="2015"><a href="#">2016</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="pastExpos">
            <div id="something">
            <h3>something</h3>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    <div id="sete">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
            <h3>dezassete</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But as soon as I change the li class="2017" from the ul under div class="status" to the ul under div class="years" (which is its intended placement), it stops working. Can you help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `<li>` class, you have to change in your Jquery too :

```
$(".2017").click(function(e) {
    x = jQuery('#sete').clone().attr("id","something");
    jQuery('#something').replaceWith(jQuery(x));
    });
```

Because you're selecting the 2017 class, if you change in HTML and not in Jquery, the selector will point to nothing.

Comment: I'm keeping the call name intact, I just change the <ul> the <li> element is inside of